# appdomain load one com dll for multiple time and keep memory isolated

Tags: memory, dll, com, appdomain, isolation

There is a COM DLL(VC6.0 ATL wizard built), I want to use appdomain's identities to impliment one process creates multiple appdomain，every one load this COM DLL and ensure everyone COM DLL to have isolated memory space。

For example

AppDomain Domain1 = AppDomain.CreateDomain("D1");
  AppDomain Domain2 = AppDomain.CreateDomain("D2");

object obj1 = Domain1.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap("UnManagedCOMDLL.dll", "UnManagedCOMDLL.ShowTag");

object obj2 = Domain2.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap("UnManagedCOMDLL.dll", "UnManagedCOMDLL.ShowTag")

In this dll,there is a global variable, every time it loads,it++. although the com loaded in different appdomain,the global variable is shared by each other.

why is such result happened? appdomain should keep memory iasolation, but it failed.

however, to managed dll, appdomain can work.

help me!!!!!

Comment: An AppDomain only keeps memory separated w.r.t. managed code as the CLR/JIT implement the isolation, it doesn't actually exist physically, it is an artificial construct. When you get native code in the mix it all goes out the window, basically there is little you can do about it.

Comment: thank you very much, it's first time I ask question here. you are the first one answer. because my software(DLL) is developed by VC6.0,nowaday one client to launch it. in future I hope to one client launch multiple of it.
any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you load the COM object into one or more hosting processes.  That is the only way you can give them the type of isolation you are looking for.  You can roll your own, or perhaps look into COM+